# Is every graph with minimum degree $n/2$ connected?

Tags: graphs, discrete-mathematics, connected

> Claim: Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ nodes, where $n$ is an even number. If every node of $G$ has degree at least $n/2$, then $G$ is connected.
>
> Decide whether the above claim is true or false, and give a proof of either the claim or a counter example.

I drew out a few examples and the claim seems to hold, and I cannot find a counter example to prove it is false, which leads me to believe the claim is true.  However, I am having a really hard time generating a proper proof.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $G$ is not connected. Consider the *smallest* connected component of $G$.

You take it from here.